# Code snippet shortcuts not working with Visual Studio 2019 and Intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, resharper, intellisense

When using Intellisennse with Visual Studio 2019 (C#) it doesn't show shortcuts anymore for my code snippets. I tried enabling Intellisense include all snippets option, but still code snippet shortcuts are not working. Any solutions for enabling shortcuts again in Visual studio?

Comment: Does code snippet shortcuts work now?

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned "my code snippets", so I suppose you used the customized code snippets.

**Please check these aspects:**

**1).** In Visual Studio 2019 > Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense > Snippets behavior, and make sure that you didn't select `Never include snippets` option by accident.

**2).** Make sure you have added related codes to your customized code snippet file(`.snippet`).

```
<Shortcut>XXXX</Shortcut>
```

And make sure that you have imported the customized code snippet file into the related folder/VS(remember to re-import(override) it if you changed some codes of `.snippet` file, and remember to choose the `Language` for CSharp).

If you indeed imported the file, the snippet file will be located in for example `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets`, you can check if it exists.

**3).** For using code snippet shortcuts, remember to press "Tab" key **twice**(once for Visual Basic, twice for C#) after you type the shortcut. For example, type XXXX in one new code line, and press "Tab" twice, and then the code snippet will be inserted.

**Besides**, there are some other troubleshooting suggestions, such as [repairing VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), [reset VS settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019#reset-settings), you can also have a try. And I'm not sure if Resharper Extension or other extensions which you installed cause this issue, perhaps you can try to disable it and test again.

**BTW**, if you mean the default keyboard shortcut key for inserting/surrounding code snippets doesn't work, please check this > Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Press shortcut keys > and make sure, the shortcut keys have been assigned(Ctrl + K/X => Edit.InsertSnippet, Ctrl + K/S => Edit.SurroundWith).

Comment: This is also true for Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Basic: Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > IntelliSense > Snippets behavior